# Using Python to pull the number of pages in all the pdf documents in a directory

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to use PyPDF2 to grab the number of pages of every pdf in a directory. I can use .getNumPages() to find the number of pages in one pdf file but I need to walk through a directory and get the number of pages for every file. Any ideas?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fileName', 'fileLocation', 'pageNumber'])
pdf=PdfFileReader(open('path/to/file.pdf','rb'))
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'Directory path'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
            df2 = pd.DataFrame([[file, os.path.join(root,file),pdf.getNumPages()]], columns=['fileName', 'fileLocation', 'pageNumber'])
            df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

This code will just add the number of pages from the first PDF file in the directory to the dataframe. If I try to add a directory path to PdfFilereader() I get a

```
PermissionError:[Errno 13] Permission denied.
```

Comment: Have you attempted to do this yourself first? If so, you should post your code and then ask for help. StackOverflow isn't a place to get people to do your work for you!

Comment: mrpopo I do appreciate that aspect of SO but he does only need two lines of code so maybe we can make an exception :)

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow! I edited my post and added my code.

Comment: Try replacing "file" with "f". I don't think it's causing the problem, but it is a python reserved word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, use

```
import glob
list_of_pdf_filenames = glob.glob('*pdf')
```

to return the list of all PDF filenames in a directory.

**Edit:  **

By placing the open() statement inside the loop, I was able to get this code to run on my computer:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fileName', 'fileLocation', 'pageNumber'])
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'/home/benjamin/docs/'):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".pdf"):
            pdf=PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(root, f),'rb'))
            df2 = pd.DataFrame([[f, os.path.join(root,f), pdf.getNumPages()]], columns=['fileName', 'fileLocation', 'pageNumber'])
            df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
print(df.head)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can find the list of all PDF filenames in the directory no problem. I'm having trouble finding the number of pages in these PDF files in the directory.

Comment: @Dillanm That is what I have been using. I just cant seem to figure out how to use that and iterate through a directory to get the number of pages for each PDF file.

Comment: @Zfrieden what is the actual value that you're using for 'Directory path'? And, if you comment out the last two lines for a moment and instead just write `print(root, file)`, what does it print?

Comment: @Benjamin the 'Directory path' is a path to a local folder on my desktop. If I print(root,file) the output is every file name in the folder with the file path.

Comment: Why is the `open()` statement not inside the loop? I would think that you would want to individually open each PDF in order to read its page numbers, right?

Comment: In other words, for each PDF file in the loop, you are trying to make a dataframe with `pdf.getNumPages()`. What is `pdf`? It's defined before the loop, so it's a constant: a PDF file reader with a single, open file: `PdfFileReader(open('path/to/file.pdf','rb'))`. Whatever's in there, it's not changing for each file in the loop; so it's not anything to do with the files you're trying to have it look at.

Comment: @Benjamin You're right the open() statement should be inside the loop but I am still unable to put the directory path in the open() statement. I get a permission error when i try to do this. If I just put a path to one file in the directory in the open() statement the column 'pageNumber' in the data frame will just have the number of pages in one PDF listed continuously.

Comment: @Benjamin Your edit worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

step 1:-

> pip install pyPDF2

step 2:-

```
import requests, PyPDF2, io
url = 'sample.pdf' 
response = requests.get(url)
with io.BytesIO(response.content) as open_pdf_file:
  read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open_pdf_file)
  num_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
  print(num_pages)
```