# Python Script for counting the number of Pages for each PDF in a directory

Tags: python, pypdf

I am new to Python, and I am trying to create a script that will list all the PDF’s in a directory and the number of pages in each of the files.

I have used the recommended code from this thread: [Using Python to pull the number of pages in all the pdf documents in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859636/using-python-to-pull-the-number-of-pages-in-all-the-pdf-documents-in-a-directory)

However, there were  two problems:

DeprecationError: PdfFileReader is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use PdfReader instead.

DeprecationError: reader.getNumPages is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use len(reader.pages) instead.

I used the recommendations but get the error:

AttributeError: 'PdfReader' object has no attribute 'len'

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this modification PdfReader works as well

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fileName', 'fileLocation', 'pageNumber'])
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'/home/papers'):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".pdf"):
            pdf=PdfReader(open(os.path.join(root, f),'rb'))
            df2 = pd.DataFrame([[f, os.path.join(root,f), len(pdf.pages)]], columns=['fileName', 'fileLocation', 'pageNumber'])
            df = pd.concat([df, df2])
print(df.head)
```

Answer (score 3):

The deprecation warning isn't very helpful. The reason is that a PDFDocument's *pages()* function returns a generator. So, in order to count the number of pages you need to exhaust the generator. You could do it like this:

```
from pdfreader import PDFDocument
from glob import glob

for file in glob('/Volumes/G-Drive/*.pdf'):
    with open(file, 'rb') as pdf:
        doc = PDFDocument(pdf)
        print(file, len(list(doc.pages())), 'pages')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use newer `pypdf` version here is the code.

Only thing you need to install is `pypdf`

`pip install pypdf`

Than you can run:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Mapping

from pypdf import PdfReader

directory = Path("C://YourDirToSearch/")

def get_num_pages(pdf_file: Path) -> int:
    reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)
    return len(reader.pages)

def get_pdf_page_numbers(directory: Path) -> Mapping[Path, int]:
    return {file: get_num_pages(file) for file in directory.glob("*.pdf")}

print(get_pdf_page_numbers(directory))
```

As a result you get something like:

```
{
 "path1.pdf": 1,
 "path2.pdf": 2,
}
```